# References of deep learning and ai for dsp researchers

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, deep-learning, books, artificial-intelligence

Are there excellent references for machine learning, deep learning and ai for DSP researchers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For understanding conv nets, I recommend works on scattering theory which provide the best explanation of their success I know of, with interpretability and mathematical rigor:

- [Lecture](https://youtu.be/4eyUReyIPXg)
- [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04920.pdf)

A precursor is the Continuous Wavelet Transform - [nice tutorial](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Eunjung/mylec/WTpart1.html).